Are qiskit and qiskit aer identical or very similar in syntax?
I can't afford a IBM full access account, and can't learn an entire programming language with only ten minutes of run time a month.
Are the qiskit lessons on YouTube/ github transferable given that I import the proper resources in my python environment?
Are any useful libraries/toolboxes designed for qiskit useable on qiskit aer, and vice versa?
Id hope so, as I'm a newbie to programming as a whole, and dont feel like scavenging the internet for resources to help me learn said languages. Id like to learn qiskit first, then pay for an account so i can do custom projects on quantum hardware.
Id appreciate any insight, thanks in advance.

You only need full access if you want to execute a lot of circuits on a real quantum processing unit (QPU). The truth is that you really don't need to run anything on a QPU unless you're doing cutting edge research, or trying to learn about the limitations of hardware. Qiskit Aer should suffice to get started, but there are alternatives even using just Qiskit. Here's a playlist of the different ways you can execute circuits within the Qiskit ecosystem: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhI5X1mNN8ghWTnnUjwjMXGosOJSeYTW4&si=ajUgLqSvMwajaNA1

So i can use qiskit as a whole for free? Unless I want ti run it on quantum hardware?

Yes. Even running circuits on hardware is free; you just have a limited amount of execution time, but 10 mins is actually a lot considering small circuits only take a few seconds to execute.
